# Convert Java Gregorian Calendar to String

Tags: java, xml, dom, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I have a Book Class and one of its attributes is:

```
private Calendar publish_date;
```

Now I would like to insert a new Book in a library.xml file. So I create a book:

```
Book b = new Book();
b.setPublish_date(new GregorianCalendar(1975, 5, 7));
```

I need that date to be a String so that I can write it in XML file (using DOM). So I perform:

```
    Element publish_date = doc.createElement("publish_date");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM DD"); 
    publish_date.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(formatter.format(b.getPublish_date())));
    book.appendChild(publish_date);
```

but this is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:301)
at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
at fileLock.FileLock.updateLibrary(FileLock.java:127)
at fileLock.FileLock.main(FileLock.java:63)
```

so which is the correct way to convert a Calendar (Gregorian Calendar) to a string? Thanks

Comment: try formatter.format(b.getPublish_date().getTime());

the format method takes a Date as the parameter type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) can't format a `GregorianCalendar`; it can format a `Date`, so convert it to a `Date` first.  You are getting `158` as the day, because `DD` is the day of the year, but `dd` (lowercase) is the day of month.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");   // lowercase "dd"
publish_date.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(formatter.format(
    b.getPublish_date().getTime() )));
```

Also, you may have known, you may not have known, but month numbers are 0-11 in Java, so when formatted, month `5` is June, so it comes out as `06`.

Output:

```
1975 06 07
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was used to using Date but sering that it's deprecated I'm starting using Gregorian Calendarian and I'm still a newbie...thanks

Comment: @LoryLory FYI [java 8 introduces a new api for date and time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/)

Comment: Isn't "Date" deprecated now?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Calendar#getTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) in order to get the correct argument for [SimpleDateformat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
publish_date.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(
    formatter.format(b.getPublish_date().getTime())));
```

Comment: Thanks but there's something which I don't understand...the date I've set in the book object is new GregorianCalendar(1975, 6, 7) so The 7th of June 1975. But in the xml file there's written <publish_date>1975 07 188</publish_date>...there's a problem with the month and the day. Why is there 188?

Comment: @LoryLory please refer to the [javadocs of that constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar-int-int-int-) the month for example is 0-based, thats why you get june instead of the expected july